# AngularJS $inject error in service injection

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-1.6

I'm newbie in Angular, so will be glad if you can help me.
I split my logic on 2 files (controllers and services).
My services code:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';    
     angular
        .module('app', [])
        .factory('authservice', authservice);

    authservice.$inject = ['$http', '$logger'];

    function authservice($http, $logger) {
        return {
            signInOwner: signInOwner,
            signUpOwner: signUpOwner
        };

        function signInOwner(owner) {

        }

        function signUpOwner(owner) {

        }
    };
})();
```

My controller code:

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

   angular
      .module('app', [])
      .controller('SignUpController', SignUpController);

   SignUpController.$inject = ['authservice'];

   function SignUpController (authservice) {
     var vm = this;
  }
})();
```

I include my services.js before controller.js but still got error about wrong authservice dependencies

> angular.js:14362 Error: [$injector:unpr]

Could you help me, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using this synthax `angular.module('app', [])`, you are **overwriting** the module creation.
You should use `angular.module('app')` to retrieve it instead.

`[]` should be use only once: at the creation of the module.

---

From the [Angular `module` doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module):

> Beware that using `angular.module('myModule', [])` will create the
>   module `myModule` and overwrite any existing module named `myModule`. Use
>   `angular.module('myModule')` to retrieve an existing module.

Answer (score 1):

In your controller code replace:

```
angular
      .module('app', [])
      .controller('SignUpController', SignUpController);
```

for

```
angular
      .module('app') // notice the lack of [] here!!
      .controller('SignUpController', SignUpController);
```

This is because with the `[]` it means you're creating the module and without it it means you're locating the module. Since the module was created  when your where creating your service, you don't need to create it again, just locate it.